# SSE intrinsics compiling MSDN code with GCC error?

Tags: gcc, struct, sse, intrinsics

I'm wondering if [Microsofts SSE intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514061%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) are a little different than the norm because I tried compiling this code with GCC with flags `-msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

int main ()
{
    __m128i a, b;

    a.m128i_u64[0] = 0x000000000000000;
    b.m128i_u64[0] = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    a.m128i_u64[1] = 0x000000000000000;
    b.m128i_u64[1] = 0x000000000000000;

    int res1 = _mm_testnzc_si128(a, b);

    a.m128i_u64[0] = 0x000000000000001;

    int res2 = _mm_testnzc_si128(a, b);

    printf_s("First result should be 0: %d\nSecond result should be 1: %d\n",
                res1, res2);

    return 0;
}
```

and it gave me the following errors:

```
sse_test_not_zero.c||In function 'main':|
sse_test_not_zero.c|8|error: request for member 'm128i_u64' in something not a structure or union|
sse_test_not_zero.c|9|error: request for member 'm128i_u64' in something not a structure or union|
sse_test_not_zero.c|9|warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type|
sse_test_not_zero.c|11|error: request for member 'm128i_u64' in something not a structure or union|
sse_test_not_zero.c|12|error: request for member 'm128i_u64' in something not a structure or union|
sse_test_not_zero.c|16|error: request for member 'm128i_u64' in something not a structure or union|
sse_test_not_zero.c|20|warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf_s'|
```

It seems to me that I need to create `struct` for `__m128i` although there might be a better solution to this problem if someone else knows of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of SSE *types* such as `__m128i` is different in Microsoft-land than in the rest of the world. If you want to write portable SSE code then stick with the intrinsics that are common to all platforms and don't make any assumptions about how the SSE vector types are defined (i.e. treat them as more-or-less opaque data types). You can implement the code in your question just using appropriate `_mm_set_xxx` intrinsics.

Comment: This is yet another reason I give the finger to Microsoft. By the way their land is eroding.

Comment: @user2555139: Microsoft has much fewer extensions than GNU for vectors, so your comment is a bit strange.